# How to apply map function to two iterables at same time?

Tags: python

I want apply `map` function in `python` to two iterables at the same time.  Below is my code but it is giving me error as
                   `t is not defined`.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
z = [5, 6, 7, 8]
y,m = map(lambda w,t: x*x,t*t, x,z)
print y
```

Is there any way to apply achieve result with `map` with two iterables ?

PS -  I am researching out map function. I understand same can be achieved with ordinary function but I want to know why above would not work ?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The problem is with your `lambda`; what's it supposed to be doing?

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Comment: Great thanks everyone. I misplaced some code and should learn more about `lambda` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fix the `lambda`, which is missing parentheses *and* referring to the wrong name:

```
lambda w, t: (w * w, t * t)
```

Second, actually *look* at the outputs from `map`, which can't be unpacked to two names:

```
[(1, 25), (4, 36), (9, 49), (16, 64)]
```

Do you want to `zip` them? `y, m = zip(*map(...))` gives `y == (1, 4, 9, 16)`.

Beyond that, as you haven't said what you're trying to achieve, it's up to you. However, as the two lists don't interact at all, it would be easier to `map` them separately.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that `lambda` should always refer to same names  inside function `(w * w, t * t)` as it is returning (`lambda w, t`)?

Comment: @GoldenPlatinum not necessarily, no; you may want to use other names too. `x` is a list here, though, so squaring it makes no sense, and there's not much point specifying parameters that are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `map` actually reads as follow: apply the `lambda` method to args `w` and `t` and return `x * x`, the iterables to apply the `map` method to are `t * t`, `x` and `z`.
It feels like you are missing the parenthesis for you `lambda` to return a tuple and that also mixed `w` and `x`. Could it be:

```
print map(lambda w,t: (w * w, t * t), x, z)
>>> [(1, 25), (4, 36), (9, 49), (16, 64)]
```

What do you expect `y` and `m` to be ? `map` returns an iterable and not a tuple. It looks like you're looking for a list of tuples rather than a single tuple